# .git/objects/pack folder space is high and how to sip those files while cloning the suite from Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab

The pack folder inside the .git folder is holding more memory(>5GB). Our project suite size is nearly 7 GB and along with that .git folder holds extra space and c:\ drive is running out of size. Is there any way to skip those files while performing checkout from Jenkins

Comment: is this a shallow clone?

Comment: Yes. It is a shallow clone with depth 1

Comment: [packfiles](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Packfiles) are the actual content of your repository - You need sufficient space to store the .git folder (pack files) and the working copy files at the same time to be able to clone a git repository. Do you have sufficient free space (13GB, from the info in the question) to clone the repo and then delete the .git folder? Are you testing a branch or releases?